# Can programatically unlock Android device when app is in the background, but not when app is killed in React Native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am using a combination of [Headless JS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) and [Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) in my Android React Native application to unlock the device and dismiss the keyguard before launching the application / bringing it to the foreground.

I can already launch the app when it is killed if the screen is unlocked. I can already unlock the screen when it is in the background. But I can't achieve a combination of these things to unlock the screen and launch the app when killed.

I use a combination of [react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) and my own native modules to do this. Here is my code that works when the app is killed but the screen is unlocked. I want to extend this so it unlocks the device when the app is killed:

index.js:

```js
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(backgroundNotificationHandler);
```

backgroundNotificationHandler.js:

```js
if (!locked && appState === BACKGROUND) {
    registerPhoneAccount();
    displayIncomingCallFromKilled(calleeName, phoneNumber, nativeCallUIUUID);
    setNativeCallUIForegroundService();
    registerNativePhoneUIEvents();
    addNativeCallUIEventListeners(nativeCallUIUUID, true, locked);
    wakeApp(calleeName);
```

nativePhoneUI.js when the above methods are:

```js
export function registerPhoneAccount() { RNCallKeep.registerPhoneAccount(); }

export function displayIncomingCallFromKilled(name, phoneNumber, nativeCallUIUUID) {
    RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(nativeCallUIUUID, phoneNumber, name);
}

export function setNativeCallUIForegroundService() {
    RNCallKeep.setForegroundServiceSettings({
        channelId: 'com.xyz',
        channelName: 'Foreground service',
        notificationTitle: 'xyz',
    });
}
export function registerNativePhoneUIEvents() { RNCallKeep.registerAndroidEvents(); }

export function addNativeCallUIEventListeners(UUIDOfNativeUI, wokenFromKilled, locked) {
    deviceWasLocked = locked;
    RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', () => {
        const { calleeCCID } = store.getState().callData;
        dismissNativeCallingUI(UUIDOfNativeUI, false);
        if (wokenFromKilled) {
            if (deviceWasLocked) {
                // Actions for handling when app was killed and device was locked
            }
            if (!deviceWasLocked) {
                if (!calleeCCID) {
                    store.dispatch(appState({ didAnswerCallFromKilled: true }));
                    RootNavigation.navigate('Loader', { title: 'Connecting..' });
                } else {
                    store.dispatch(answerCall(calleeName));
                }
            }
        } else {
            store.dispatch(answerCall(calleeName));
        }
    });
    endCallFromListener = true;
}

export function wakeApp(name) {
    calleeName = name;
    RNCallKeep.backToForeground();
    if (deviceWasLocked) {
        NativeModules.DeviceLock.unlock();
        deviceWasLocked = false;
    }
}
```

DeviceLock.java:

```
package com.fleeting;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.content.Context;

public class DeviceLock extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "DeviceLock";
    }

        private ReactContext mReactContext;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock sCpuWakeLock;
        private Activity activity;

    public DeviceLock(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
                mReactContext = reactContext;
    }

    /* React Methods */
   @ReactMethod
    public void unlock() {
                    activity = mReactContext.getCurrentActivity();

                    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) mReactContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    int flags = PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK 
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP 
                            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE;
                    sCpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(flags, activity.getClass().getName());
                    sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
    
                    activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                            activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
                            activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
                }

                    activity.getWindow().addFlags(
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON 
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                            
                        });
                    }
                    
                    @ReactMethod
                    public void lock() {
                        sCpuWakeLock.release();
    
                        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                                activity.setShowWhenLocked(false);
                                activity.setTurnScreenOn(false);
                    }
    
                        activity.getWindow().clearFlags( 
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON 
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                            });
                }
}
```

I believe the problem is that if I use the Native Module when the app is killed, there is no activity which is why it might not work?

How can I change my code to programatically unlock the device when it is killed?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe you need a background service?

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to unlock the device / dismiss the keyguard when the app has been killed and the device is locked. It already works when the app is in the background (screen unlocks), or when the app is killed (app launches) but the screen is not locked.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned a background service. This could even run when your app itself is killed. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services